# Comparing millisecond timestamps in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hdfs, impala

I have 2 timestamp columns stored in an HDFS that I can access through Impala, hive, etc...

The timestamps that I need to compare may look like this example:

2014-04-08 00:23:21.687000000

2014-04-08 00:23:21.620000000

With differences in the milliseconds, and need to build a new column that in this example should have a value of 0.067000

I've tried using impala's [built in time functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) but none of them seem to make the cut. 
I've tried:

1. casting the string to a timestamp and then substracting the 2 values. This returns an error "AnalysisException: Arithmetic operation requires numeric operands"
2. using the unix_timestamp function. This truncates the values to an int that represent seconds, so subsecond values are lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writting this question I found the answer :)

The way to do it was using a double cast.

Cast(cast(time_stamp) as timestamp) as double)

this makes the times_stamp into a number without truncating sub-second values.

Once there it becomes a trivial arithmetic operation.